# How to use partial matches across multiple columns in R to set final value

Tags: r, vba

I am new to R, moving over from Excel VBA. I would like to categorize a final value based on the text provided in multiple columns and 20k+ rows.

I've been semi-successful with "if" and "identical" but have struggled with partial matches through using "grep"

I'll share psuedo-code of what I'm trying to achieve:

```r
If d$Removal_Reason_Code contains "SCH" AND
    If d$Shop_Action_Code is an exact match to "Test" AND 
       If d$Repair_Summary contains "No Fault Found"
Then 
 set d$Category to "NFF" 

Else 
go back to row 1 and check against other keywords
```

I can post the working VBA code if that is helpful. I'm just getting my head round how R works, and was hoping it may be a quick and easy answer for one of you gurus!

Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `grepl` for partial matches

```
i1 <-  with(d, grepl("SCH",  Removal_Reason_Code) & Shop_Action_Code  == "TEST" &
     grepl("No Fault Found", Repair_Summary))
d$Category[i1] <- "NFF"
```